# MySQL user created via command line can't access PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, access-control

I'm trying to create a read-only user with access to one database in PHPMyAdmin.  Since I'm a server newbie I followed some instructions line-by-line on setting up my database and PHPMyAdmin.  As such, my root account is not accessible via the GUI; only a full access child account.  This account cannot create users via the GUI, so I did the following via command line:

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql> create user 'readonly-user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
mysql> grant select on mydatabase.* to 'readonly-user'@'localhost';
```

If I try to log in via PHPMyAdmin as readonly-user, however, I'm not able to get in.

Is there something I need to do to register this account with PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: I copied-and-pasted your MySQL commands to create 'readonly-user'@'localhost' and once that was done I was able to log in to phpMyAdmin as that user without difficulty. What error message(s), if any, do you get when you try to log in?

Comment: anyone solved this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run the `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` command.

Comment: Are there any special variants?  I ran the command and then tried to log into PHPMyAdmin as readonly-user.  I'm still getting "#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server"

Comment: I've tried to recreate the issue on my server and so far have not been successful. After creating 'readonly-user'@'localhost' I was able to log in to phpMyAdmin as that user immediately; no `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` was required.

Comment: @GordThompson Ok, thanks for trying.  I have a few leads I'm investigating, so I'll post an answer if I find out what it is.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` is only required when you manipulate the underlying grant tables directly with DML *instead of* using statements like `CREATE USER` and `GRANT`.

Comment: anyone solved this problem?

Comment: In my case, it was just dumb user error.  I was manipulating a mysql DB on the web server, but PHPMyAdmin was pointed to the DB server.  Thus, nothing I did mattered.